# Let $p$ be a prime number. Prove that for $a \in\mathbb Z, 0 \le a \le p−1$: $C(a, p - 1) \equiv (-1)^a\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$C(a, p-1) = \frac{(p-1)!}{a!(p-1-a)!}$

If $a$ is an odd number, then $C(a, p-1)  \equiv p - 1 \pmod p$

If $a$ is an even number, then $C(a, p-1)  \equiv 1 \pmod p$

I'm stuck and I don't know how to proceed, I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the following polynomial identity in $\mathbb Z[x]$:

$$x^p+1=(x+1)(x^{p-1}-x^{p-2}+\ldots+(-1)^{p-2}x+(-1)^{p-1})$$

This identity is also valid in $F_p[x]$ (coefficients reduced modulo $p$. $F_p$ is the field of remainders modulo $p$).

However, in $F_p[x]$ we also have that:

$$x^p+1=(x+1)^p$$

Namely, in $\mathbb Z[x]$, take all the coefficients modulo $p$, and note that the coefficients on the right side are all (except for the first and the last) divisible by $p$, as they are of the form $C(a,p)={p \choose a}=\frac{p!}{a!(p-a)!}$ where $p$ is the factor in the numerator but not in the denominator. So, in $F_p$ all the coefficients barring the first and the last one must be zero.

Thus, in $F_p[x]$ we have that:

$$(x+1)^{p-1}=x^{p-1}-x^{p-2}+\ldots+(-1)^{p-2}x+(-1)^{p-1}$$

and comparing the coefficients and using binomial formula, you get that:

$$C(a,p-1)={p-1\choose a}=(-1)^a$$

in $F_p$, which is the same as the claim you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $a! = 1\cdot2\cdots a = (p-(p-1))(p-(p-2)
\cdots (p-(p-a)) \equiv (-1)^a (p-a) 
\cdots (p-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Using [Pascal's Identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Pascal%27s_Identity)

$$\binom{p-1}k\equiv-\binom{p-1}{k-1}\pmod p $$   as $p$ divides $\displaystyle\binom pk$ for $1\le k\le p-1$

$$\implies\binom{p-1}k\equiv(-1)^r\binom{p-1}{k-r}\pmod p$$  for $0\le r\le k$

Set $r=k$